# Return alternate elements of 3 given lists. Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

This procedure is supposed to return a list with alternative values from 3 given lists. So for example (alt ('a b c)'(1 2 3)'(i j k)) should return '(a 1 i b 2 j c 3 k).

This is my logic so far. I would take the first element of each list and recursively call the procedure again with cdr as the new arguments.

```
(define (alternate lst1 lst2 lst3)
    (cons (car lst1)
          (cons (car lst2)
                (cons (car lst3)
                (alternate (cdr lst1)(cdr lst2)(cdr lst3))))))
```

The error occurs in

```
(cons (car lst1)
```

"mcar: contract violation

expected: mpair?

given()"

(cons a d) returns a newly allocated pair whose first element is a and second element is d. But since there are 3 not 2 given lists, is there another way to approach creating lists?

Would this be another approach?

```
(define (alternate lst1 lst2 lst3)
    (list (car lst1)(car lst2)(car lst3))
        (alternate (cdr lst1)(cdr lst2)(cdr lst3)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add empty list check to avoid the error. So your code should look like this:

```
(define (alternate lst1 lst2 lst3)
  (if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2) (null? lst3))
      '()
      (cons (car lst1)
        (cons (car lst2)
          (cons (car lst3)
            (alternate (cdr lst1)(cdr lst2)(cdr lst3)))))))
```

If you can use SRFI-1 (or more precisely `append-map`), then you can also write like this:

```
(define (alt l1 l2 l3) (append-map list l1 l2 l3))
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the following standard Scheme:

```
(define (alternate . lists)
  (apply append (apply map list lists)))
```

Not very optimized, but does the job :)

Eval: http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=175